# Kali Linux 2016.2 sound problem

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, audio

I decided to install Linux as I feed up with getting notification from windows that tell me to get my software licence.It is not the one reason why I move to Linux but it is another topic.
Anyway,I installed Kali Linux 2016.1 and I have some issues with sounds which is so noisy,squeaky sound.Later ,I decided to upgrade to 2016.02.But thats not solve the problem,still same problem with voice.How can I fix this problem.

My Linux distro :Kali Linux 2016.2 32  bit,i386arch.

My hardware: Acer Laptop

Sound driver :I guess it is pulseaudio.

The output of the `lsmod|grep snd` is like this.

> snd_hda_codec_hdmi     40960  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek    65536  1
>   snd_hda_codec_generic    65536  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel 
>   28672  3 snd_hda_codec          94208  4
>   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
>   snd_hda_core           57344  5
>   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
>   snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec snd_pcm
>   86016  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
>   snd_timer              28672  1 snd_pcm snd                    57344 
>   14
>   snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
>   soundcore              16384  1 snd

and the command of `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`
is:

> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio
>   Controller (rev 03)   Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 82801I (ICH9
>   Family) HD Audio Controller   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency
>   0, IRQ 29     Memory at 96700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>     Capabilities:    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
>     Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
>
> 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express
>   Port 1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])

Comment: User who downvoted ,pls give me your reason why downvote.Question is clear and understanable.

Comment: identify your sound card with `lsmod | grep snd` and `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`, you can edit your answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/343688/edit)

Comment: Did you try to adjust some sound levels? Like PCM? If it is set too high it can result in poor sound quality.

Comment: Run the following `modprobe snd-hda-intel` then `speaker-test`

Comment: @GAD3R ı APPLYED MODPROBE command but no speaker-test command available even in my repository

Comment: run `apt install alsa-base alsa-utils alsa-tools libasound2 `

Comment: just I can hear noisy voice with this output;speaker-test 1.1.3

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 192 to 2097152
Period size range from 64 to 699051
Using max buffer size 2097152
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 524288
was set buffer_size = 2097152
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 10,943683
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 10,949661
 0 - Front Left

Time per period = 10,948591
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 10,946322

Comment: Do you mean "squeaky" as in "has higher pitch than it ought to"? Or something else? What kind of noise do you get? Humming/buzzing, or sound interruptions (dropouts)? You have an Intel HDA Soundcard with a Realtek codec, and usually those work quite well under Linux (I have one here as well). Which applications did you use to produce sound besides speaker-test?

Comment: @dirkt mean a harsh, scratching sound ,it sounds like ..emm..listening an old ancient  radio...I can hear the sound ..but lots of the noisy background.. while I am listening music on youtube or mplayer,or on skype..

Comment: @Kalavan yea it seems PCM level an issue.but when I made it low ,I can't hear the music well.

Comment: Could be [clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28signal_processing%29): One or some amplifiers on the sound path are set too high. Have a look at `alsamixer`, and play around with the amplification levels. For starters, put everything in middle range or so.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are two main sound volumes (at least in `alsamixer`). One should be called 'main' or 'master' second one 'pcm'. You should use first one to set volume.  Second one shouldn't be set to high as this is amplification and can produce sound peaks that your hardware won't handle.  Also some programs tries to use pcm as volume setting - this should be reconfigured.